# Transaction rollback

Tags: rollback, transaction

I am hoping if you can help clarify the rollback on transactions, for scenario below.
For example if we have the piece of code below

```
MyCustomObject__c customObj = new MyCustomObject__c ();
Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
try{
   insert customObj;
}catch(Exception e){
  Database.rollback(sp);
}
```

if we have another user using the same app, and is submitting a save on a new Opportunity object at the same time as the above rollback is happening, would the rollback affect the Opportunity object being saved at same time  or is it just on the customObject?
Thanks

Comment: note in your example above, if the try block is only doing one DML operation, and it fails, no rollback is required. Rollback is typically used in the pattern you have when there are multiple DML operations within the try block and if any of them fail, all prior successful DMLs within the `try{...}` also need to rollback

Comment: thanks for the note @crop1645, I am  doing multiple DML operations but my my code but this example was just short way to explain my question about other user actions happening sametime as  rollback

Comment: np, I made the comment more for others who might come across this post in the future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any DML operations in the same transaction performed after Database.setSavePoint would be rolled back. This means that multiple users (and even the same user in multiple transactions) are isolated from each other, so the opportunity would be unaffected.